# Locale.getISOCountries() Wrapper

Tags: java

I have the following codes, i want to get a list of country **CODE** and **NAME** from `Locale.getISOCountries()` and set it into my custom made class, i managed to do it but i somehow feel that my codes is not clean enough, especially the `getCountryList()` part but i not sure how to minimize it, is there any suggestion? I don't mind to use lambda if possible.

```
private static List<CountryPair> getCountryList()
{
    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
    List<String> countryCodes = Arrays.asList(locales);
    List<CountryPair> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
    countryCodes.forEach(code -> {
    CountryPair pair = new CountryPair();
    Locale locale = new Locale("", code);
    pair.setValue(locale.getCountry());
    pair.setDisplayName(locale.getDisplayCountry());
    pairList.add(pair);
    });
  return pairList;
}
```

Country pair class:

```
public class CountryPair {

    private String value;

    private String displayName;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
      return displayName;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
      this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is: create a constructor for CountryPair, which takes the parameter values:

```
    public CountryPair(String value, String displayName) {
        this.value = value;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
```

Then, you can use an elegant map-chain:

```
    List<CountryPair> pairList = countryCodes.stream()
        .map(code -> new Locale("", code))
        .map(locale -> new CountryPair(locale.getCountry(), locale.getDisplayCountry()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, you could also use a constructor which uses the Locale object as a parameter.